# How can I pass variable with concatenation to get an option in selection list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to get an option in a select list by it's value.
I 'd like to replace `[value="1"]` by `idEntrepot` but it doens't work.

```
 var $enrepotOrg = $('#appbundle_operation_entrepotOrigine');
 $enrepotOrg.change(function () {

 var idEntrepot = $enrepotOrg.val();
 $('#appbundle_operation_entrepotDestine option[value="1"]').hide();

  //.........
```

I'd like just to pass var idEntrepot instead of static "1"

Comment: please share the select html

Comment: Sorry I work with symfony and twig, so the form is not an html , but it will be converted to html after execution.

Comment: I'd like just to pass var idEntrepot instead of  static "1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function hideOption() {
  $('#test option').show();
  var valueToHide = $("#edit").val();
  $('#test option[value="' + valueToHide + '"]').hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="test">
  <option value="">None</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

<input id="edit" /> 
<button onclick="hideOption()">Click</button>
```

Comment: I'd like just to pass var idEntrepot instead of static "1"

Comment: yes it's working now . I'll acept your answer after 5 minutes ;)